# Get symbol produced by key event

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I'm working on user input by handling `keydown` event.
And it's very tiring to figure out which character was entered.
For example, I'm checking `event.keyCode == 86` if it was `v` letter, but if I want to know if it was `#` symbol I need to check `event.keyCode == 51 && event.shiftKey`, and so on.
So, my question is there any simplier way to detect which character will be produced by current `event`?

Comment: What is the higher level use case for this?

Comment: There is no simpler approach but it's not clear what you need to use the keys for?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to prevent non alpha-numeric symbols

Comment: OK...then think of it differently and look at the key code ranges instead. Letters and numbers fall in specific ranges. If code not in those ranges then prevent them

Comment: @charlietfl inconvenience is that I need to prevent `event.keyCode == 51` only if shift-key is pressed. I thought that there might be a more elegant method. If it is not, then okay

Comment: @charlietfl I would use `pattern` attribute... if it was an input, but I have a `contenteditable` element :)

Comment: So if it's in letters/numbers ranges...accept it. Add another check for 51 and shift. Reject all others. Not really complicated. Also probably need to consider `paste` event

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) attribute, and check if it matches a RegExp pattern (`whiteList`) that include the characters you allow.

**Note:** since the code can also be `shift`, `ctrl`, etc... the pattern is limited to a single character.

```js
var whiteList = /^[\w\d]$/;

demo.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  var key = e.key;
  
  console.log(key, whiteList.test(key));
});
```

```html
<input id="demo">
```

Comment: Code is good but not helps: the problem is to consider with shift key

Comment: It works with a shift key as well. Check it - 3 is `true` while shift 3 is `false`.